Unable to join Windows 11 Client but Windows 10 Client works just fine
I'm currently facing this issue right now. I can join any Windows 10 computer to the domain just fine and before the 24h2 Windows 11, I can join those client running Windows 11 just fine.
I'm thinking it's due to the version since my DC1 & 2 are still WinSvr2012r2. But today, I received another sets of PC (Dell Optiplex 7020 MFF) running 24H2 and decided to downgrade first to 23H2.
It ended up failed. Previously it works on a new client computer running the same version of Windows 11 and Model.
I've kinda confused right now since it works with freshly installed Windows 10 Pro client. And it did work with the downgrade method before. Therefore, I can assume my DCs are working just fine.
Do you think this can be caused by the BIOS itself? Appreciate if anyone can hint something to  make it work before I try to downgrade to Windows 10 Pro instead which I prefer not to.
Thank you in advance.

What about actual errors? And your Active Directory servers are indeed off topic and will be problematic.

have you read this - or done any research at all?
